# Can I use Adobe Fuse CC models in my commercial game?

Tags: models, licensing

I'm wondering if it's allowed to use Adobe Fuse CC models and textures in a commercial game?

I use this software to get good shapes of character and then use Blender to modify the body or renew texture.

Comment: What does the license say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

See the PDF document that can be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/go/fuseterms) on Adobe's website.

Additionally, [this page on Adobe's forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1992542) describes a bit more in layman's terms what you can and can't do with Adobe Fuse CC.

In summary, you can produce commercial games and DLCs for your commercial games, but you can't produce assets that you will sell on different assets stores.

---

For your convenience, here is the relevant part of the PDF:

> 1. Additional Definitions:
>
>    1. Animation Data means 1) animation files in BVH, FBX, OBJ or Collada formats containing data owned by or licensed to Adobe; and 2) Fuse 3D animation models.
>    2. End Use means the derivative application or product created by you, into which the Animation Data, or derivations thereof, is embedded, for your use or your customer's use.
>    3. User Characters means the 3D characters created by you or provided by you using 3 rd party software.
> 2. License Grant. Subject to your compliance with the Terms, Adobe grants you a personal, non-exclusive, non-sublicensable and non-transferable license to use the Animation Data to create an End Use. You may reproduce and distribute Animation Data only in connection with the End Use. You may modify the Animation Data prior to embedding such Animation Data in the End Use. Redistribution, republication or commercialization of Animation Data separate from or outside of the End Use is strictly prohibited.
> 3. Restrictions. Except as expressly granted in Section 2 (License Grant), you cannot (i) modify, reverse engineer, copy, reproduce, republish, upload, or (ii) rent, lease, sell, transmit, sublicense or otherwise distribute the Animation Data.
> 4. Proprietary Rights. Other than the rights granted herein, Adobe retains all right, title and interest in and to the Animation Data. Except as expressly granted in Section 2 (License Grant), you have 1) no rights to modify or make derivative works of the Animation Data, and 2) no license, right or interest in any Adobe patent, trademark, copyright, trade name or service mark is granted hereunder. You agree not to export the Animation Data in violation of UN embargoes or US laws and regulations.
> 5. User Characters. You may use and modify User Characters in connection with the Services and the Animation Data.

Note that this not the complete license that comes with the software, and in any case replaces it; you should read and agree with the license that comes with the software.